# ExchangeDeclare method for RabbitMQ on Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, rabbitmq

When I look at the API for IModel found here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/c165ffdab5cbf3cfb8ace73b3872bd3f24464225/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/api/IModel.cs
Then `ExchangeDeclare` looks like 

`[AmqpMethodDoNotImplement(null)]
        void ExchangeDeclare(string exchange, string type, bool durable, bool autoDelete,
            IDictionary<string, object> arguments);`

But when I reference the dotnet RabbitMQ.Client from a Mono project and the go to the declaration in the assembly browser then `ExchangeDeclare` looks likes

    `void ExchangeDeclare (string exchange, string type, bool passive, bool durable, bool autoDelete, bool @internal, [AmqpNowaitArgument (null)] bool nowait, IDictionary arguments);`

and the compiler says it does not know a method with 5 arguments.

My code compiles fine with Visual Studio but not with OSX/Mono

I am using Mono version 
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.0 (mono-4.4.0-branch/fcf7a6d Tue Apr 26 11:53:52 EDT 2016)

Does anyone have an idea about what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the same version of RabbitMQ.Client? It looks like the `nowait` parameter has been removed in 2011: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/log/4109d26abc2d/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/api/IModel.cs

Comment: Yes. I am referencing the same version of the DLL.